# Jquery to php variable in the same page without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, nginx

I am working on a small PHP script hosted on Nginx + CloudFlare and it seems like there is a problem with headers. The problem is cookies sometimes there is a confusion so Nginx send false headers with false cookies so i can't get the right cookies using : $_COOKIE but when using document.cookie i still can get the right cookie so is there any solution to pass the document.cookie variable into PHP in the same page without refresh ?
Javascript :

```
Document.cookie
```

Or is there any solution for the headers issue ?

Comment: Not without a HTTP request. Because PHP code executes on the server side before the JavaScript code will be executed on the client side.

Comment: Use ajax to send it to the backend and on the php side set the cookie and than do the code you need.